# Mediaplayer stops in android after 30 clicks

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-sound

I've seen other posts on this but I cant figure out problem.

So I'm designing a calculator and all the numbers have one onclick method and all the operators have different . I have a method playSound() where the code is:

```
public void playSound(){

         MediaPlayer mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.btn);

        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        if(mp.isPlaying())
        {
            mp.stop();
            mp.reset();
        }
            mp.start();


    }
```

I've tried release to. Can anyone let me know the efficient way to write this.
I call this method inside the onclick methods. But after around 30 clicks it stops. I've also tried to create MediaPlayer global but it still stops. I've read mediaplayer is actually costly so we can use soundpool. But even soundpool is deprecated. Any help?

Comment: Are you trying a different sound or is it always the same R.raw.btn ?

Comment: I'ts always the same. I know I dont need to assign it every time but I was just messing around to find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement onComplition() Listener , and in that listener you can call release method

You created multiple instances of mediaplayer and not release mediaplayer instanace thats why issue is came
After you release called your issue will be resolved

Comment: In my case when each button is pressed it calls this method. So technically   in calculator the sounds keep playing with push of a button, So when should i release mediaplayer?

Comment: It is possible to declare mediaPlayer variable global and creare obj only once ?

Comment: What i tried, was to define a mediaplayer mp globally and during oncreate i  did following:
mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.btn);
and doing this stops the sound after like 10 clicks

Comment: Ok implement onCompletion listener and write code mp.release in oncompletion method, remove global variable

Comment: I check working perfectly, in your side issue is still coming

Comment: This Worked! Thank you Very much, I've accepted the answer. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Initialize the MediaPlayer as a class attribute:

```
MediaPlayer media = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. btn);
```

In the playSound() method:

```
public void playSound(){
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.reset();
        mp.start();
    }
```